# Angular js Properties in Selected object is not accessible in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
 <select id="singleselect" ng-model="selectedQuestion" class="form-control select2" 
 ng-options="x.Title for x in tabnames">
 </select>
```

now when i access the value if `{{selectedQuestion.Title}}`  i am getting proper value,
when i am accessing value of `{{selectedQuestion.ID}}`  also i am getting proper value,

what i actually need is value of `{{selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix}}` to be accessed in model(javascript) but it cannot be accessed neither in UI with `{{selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix}}` nor in model like

```
 $scope.Newmodel = {
        Title: "New Question Title",
        ControlPrefix: $scope.selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix
    };
```

basicaly i want the value inside the  `$scope.Newmodel.ControlPrefix` variable  i.e `$scope.Newmodel.ControlPrefix`

```
 **tabnames array/objet is below**
   {
  "$id": "1",
  "ID": 3,
  "Title": "Text",
  "ControlPrefix": "txt"
  },

  {
 "$id": "2",
 "ID": 4,
 "Title": "Number",
 "ControlPrefix": "num"
  },
```

Comment: Title is accessible in model?

Comment: Yes, Title can be accessible in UI like {{selectedQuestion.Title}}
But in Model it didnt work

Comment: did you mean `$scope.Newmodel.ControlPrefix` or `$scope.selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix` ? because that is what you use for the `ng-model`

Comment: Suggest you provide a [mcve]. Hard to debug without full code context

Comment: $scope.Newmodel = {
         Title: "New Question Title",
         ControlPrefix: $scope.selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix
          };
Here i am trying to sync value of $scope.selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix inside $scope.Newmodel, i.e when i am accessing the value of $scope.Newmodel.ControlPrefix i should able to get that value.

Comment: I don't know what you want to ask. what's the context of $scope.Newmodel here? Will you please tell us _

Comment: @user3815413 why don't you just use `ng-model="Newmodel"` instead?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/9147/
Now at UI the value is coming but not at the model,
Basically i want to set the value of NewQuestionmodel.QuestionTypeID
(Example link above)

Comment: @ManishSingh i am passing entire NewQuestionmodel to webservice and it consist lot of other properties.truncated all those properties to minimize the above eg

Answer (score 2):

I don't See any problem with this, please check and verify -

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myCntr",function($scope){
$scope.tabnames = [
  {
  "$id": "1",
  "ID": 3,
  "Title": "Text",
  "ControlPrefix": "txt"
  },

  {
 "$id": "2",
 "ID": 4,
 "Title": "Number",
 "ControlPrefix": "num"
  },]
  $scope.NewQuestionmodel = {
      Title: "",
      QuestionTypeID: "",
    };   
  $scope.Dosomething = function(selectedQuestion){
  $scope.NewQuestionmodel.Title = selectedQuestion.Title;
  $scope.NewQuestionmodel.QuestionTypeID= selectedQuestion.ID;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntr">
   <select id="singleselect" ng-model="selectedQuestion" class="form-control select2" 
 ng-options="x.Title for x in tabnames" ng-change="Dosomething(selectedQuestion)">
 </select>
<br>

<span>FRom UI - Selected Question Title : {{selectedQuestion.Title}} </span><br>
<span>From UI - Selected Question ID : {{selectedQuestion.ID}} </span><br>
<span>From UI - Selected Question ControlPrefix : {{selectedQuestion.ControlPrefix}} </span><br><br>
 <br>
<span>Selected Question Title from Backend is {{NewQuestionmodel.Title}}</span><br>
<span>Selected Question ID from Backend is {{NewQuestionmodel.QuestionTypeID}}</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/9147/
Now at UI the value is coming but not at the model, Basically i want to set the value of NewQuestionmodel.QuestionTypeID (Example link above)

Comment: @user3815413 You have to do it on change event